# Get default browser settings like TimeZone, Dateformat, timeFormat and language using javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, momentjs, navigator

How we can get all of the default browser/system/country settings using javascript or any other js library?

1. Like what is the default timezone format of the browser?
   (UTC+05:30 or UTC+01:00, etc)
2. What is the default Date format according to timezone? ('DD/MM/YYYY' or
   'MM/DD/YYYY' or 'YYYY/MM/DD')
3. What is the default Time format according to a browser? ('AM/PM' or '24 Hour')
4. Default language of browser?

   - If we do **navigator.language** using javascript we get "en-GB" but can we get a full form? like English, Spanish, Sweedish or etc
5. Default temperature unit? (Celsius or Fahrenheit)

Answer (score 0):

> Like what is the default timezone format of the browser? (UTC+05:30 or UTC+01:00, etc)

Timezone is a preference, there is no default. [Be careful about what you assume](https://gist.github.com/timvisee/fcda9bbdff88d45cc9061606b4b923ca)

To get the timezone offset, which is the number of minutes you need to subtract from UTC, use the following. This will usually be a negative number for users in Asia and Australia, and usually a positive number for users in the Americas.

```
new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
```

If you want to know the timezone, you can get it with

```js
Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone
// => "Atlantic/Reykjavik"
// => "Americas/New_York"
// => "Asia/Shanghai"
```

Be careful if you translate this to a 3 character abbreviation. "Americas/New_York" could be "EST" or "EDT" depending on the time of year. "CST" could be China standard time, or Cuba standard time, or Central Australia standard time, or Central America standard time.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl

Answer (score -1):

Other than temperature unit (which the browser knows nothing about), the IETF language setting (in this case "en-GB") tells the browser how to format outputs when using .toLocaleString(). A date object will be printed with the TZ offset, the same date with `.toLocalDateString()` will give the date in proper locale 'DD/MM/YYYY' , and the same date with `.toLocaleTimeString()` will give the time with 'AM/PM or 24h' representation.

```js
const date = new Date();
console.log(date.toString());
console.log(date.toUTCString());
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString());
// Get TZ for instance
const tz = date.toString().match(/GMT(-|\+)[0-9]{4}.*/)[0];
console.log(tz);
```

Comment: These things will give the time and details things but I need its default format.

Comment: Sure - that is what I tried to explain. The "default format" that you are after is determined by navigator.language. In you question, that value is en-GB.

Comment: The 'default format' is implemented in JavaScript using the language tag with the [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

Comment: `/GMT-[0-9]{4}.*/` will fail because the fourth char could be a `-` or a `+`. Trying to parse `new Date().toString()` is going to be a quite fragile.